# Is it reasonable to move logic from child to parent if multiple instances of child will be created?

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-component, react-functional-component

Let's assume I have a  functional component (parent) that will render 10  functional components (children). Would it be better to move all the logic and functions of the  component to the parent component and pass the required functions as props to improve app performance (memory)?

Comment: Are children of the same type?

Comment: Yes, same type. <Guide /> (singular, without s) in this case

Comment: depends on the logic you want to implement. You will only write one file for a single child component and in the parent, you will create a list of children. If the logic I work with contains state and the functions also use state, then I use it in the parent component.

Comment: What about logic? Does it change the state of the parent component?

Comment: MonkeyDLuffy, got it, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Taras Mykhalchuk, no, the logic is only concerned with the child component